# How to set the checkbox in the first column based on the value in the second column of a table?

Tags: java, selenium, browser-automation

I'm automating a task using Java and Selenium.

I want to set a checkbox (which is in the first column of a table) based on whether the value in the second column matches my input value. For example, in the following code snippet, the value "Magnus" matches my input value so I want to set the checkbox associated with it.

```
<table class="cuesTableBg" width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="0" summary="Find List Table Result">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="cuesTableBg">
        <tr class="cuesTableRowEven">
        <tr class="cuesTableRowOdd">
            <td align="center">
                <input class="content-nogroove" type="checkbox" name="result[1].chked" value="true">
                <input type="hidden" value="1c62dd7a-097a-d318-df13-75de31f54cb9" name="result[1].col[0].stringVal">
                <input type="hidden" value="Magnus" name="result[1].col[1].stringVal">
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <a class="cuesTextLink" href="userEdit.do?key=1c62dd7a-097a-d318-df13-75de31f54cb9">Magnus</a>
            </td>
            <td align="left"></td>
            <td align="left">Carlsen</td>
            <td align="left"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="cuesTableRowEven">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But I'm unable to do it. In the above case, the following two lines serve the purpose (as my input value matches with that in the second row):

```
WebElement checkbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type = 'checkbox' and @name = 'result[1].chked']"));
checkbox.click();
```

But it can't be used as the required value might not always be in the second row.

I tried following code block but to no avail:

```
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@summary = 'Find List Table Result']//tr"));
for (WebElement row : rows) {
    WebElement userID = row.findElement(By.xpath(".//td[1]"));
    if(userID.getText() == "Magnus") {
        WebElement checkbox = row.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type = 'checkbox']"));
        checkbox.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

For what it's worth, XPath of the text in the second column:

```
/html/body[@id='mainbody']/table/tbody/tr/td/div[@id='contentautoscroll']/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/a
```

I don't know about [CSS Selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323884/parsing-html-table-data-with-xpath-and-selenium-in-java). Will it help here?

Comment: Yes, CSS selectors must help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the input value already you just use below xpath to select respected checkbox

```
"//a[text(),'Magnus']/parent::td/preceding-sibling::td/input[@type='checkbox']"
```

Update:

```
"//a[text()='Magnus']/parent::td/preceding-sibling::td/input[@type='checkbox']"
```

Comment: You can call findElement method on a WebElement. It's absolutely fine. It's also mentioned on the link shared by you. See the third method in 'Method Summary'.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong info. I shall update my answer to not to mislead any further user. Thank you so much for pointing my mistake.

Comment: have you tried above xpath to access that checkbox based on the value?

Comment: Yeah, I tried the given xpath but it didn't work. I'm still stuck and trying to see if 'CSS Selectors' can help me out or not.

Comment: updated with correct xpath. Try with that. I've tried in my machine it is working with given HTML.

Comment: Spot on!!!
The following code snippet, that makes use of the XPath given by you, does the trick:

WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='cuesTableBg']"));
        
WebElement checkbox = table.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[text()='Magnus']/parent::td/preceding-sibling::td/input[@type='checkbox']"));

checkbox.click();

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs and the final working answer. Also, can you please tell me a comprehensive source that lists and explains rarely used constructs like 'preceding-sibling' with examples? :)

Comment: :) It is my pleasure to help you 
http://goo.gl/DWqYC , || http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp || http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp You can find some info related to xpath in above links.

Answer (score 0):

While comparing two strings `equals` should be used instead of `==`

Replace

```
 if(userID.getText() == "Magnus")
```

with

```
String check1 = userID.getText();
if(check1.equals("Magnus")
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out but the focus here is on the problem of clicking the checkbox. After being able to match the text in the second column with the desired value, I should be able to set the checkbox in the first column of the same row. I'm unable to do it. That's the main concern!

Comment: Let me know the website you are testing if it is not confidential, so that i can help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, the site is accessible only internally. I added the XPath of one of the elements. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it was a silly mistake on my part. The following code snippet, a fairly straightforward one, worked.

```
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='cuesTableBg']//tr"));

for (WebElement row : rows) {
    WebElement secondColumn = row.findElement(By.xpath(".//td[2]"));
    if(secondColumn.getText().equals("Magnus")) {
        WebElement checkbox = row.findElement(By.xpath(".//td[1]/input"));
        checkbox.click();
        break;      
    }   
}
```